# how to center the scroll view inside the View

Tags: ios, swift

I have a scroll view added to the View Controller's View. On iPhone XR, the scroll view subviews appear to the left because the scrollView does not expand its parent's view and is not centered. How can I make the scroll view take the full width and height of its parent's view and center it?

Comment: If you facing issues on scrollViews. Try to use a tableView and inside that use a view and you can expand and scroll how long you want. Make sure you applied the constrains correctly to tableView.

Comment: align horizontally center the scrollview with the containing view. Further, constraint the widths of containing view and scrollview to be equal.

Answer (score 1):

add below constraint to scrollview

```
 scrollview.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    self.view.addSubview(scrollview)
    scrollview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant : 0).isActive = true
    scrollview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor, constant : 0).isActive = true
    scrollview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor, constant :0).isActive = true
    scrollview.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    scrollview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Comment: do I add in viewDidLoad?